# How to Configure FAST Search in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: configuration, fast-search

Friends,

Can anyone please refer me to some links or step-by-step guide on HOW TO CONFIGURE FAST SEARCH for Sharepoint 2010.

After configuring it what settings need to be made in Central Admin to enable it to crawl other Sharepoint 2007 server.

Regards,

Ketan

Answer (score 2):

These resources helped me with install and config:

[FAST Search Step-By-Step install](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2009/11/28/FAST-Search-Step-by-Step-Install.aspx)

[Deployment (FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381267.aspx) - Technet

Not sure about crawling the SharePoint 2007 server - though you should have a look at [Crawling Web content with the FAST Search Web crawler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383271.aspx).

Comment: You would not use the FAST web crawler, but crawl as a SharePoint source, but you would most likely add a crawl rule specifying the crawl account to be used.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Installing-and-Configuring-SharePoint-2010-and-FAST-Search-2010e28093Part-4.aspx

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Installing-and-Configuring-SharePoint-2010-and-FAST-Search-2010e28093Part-5.aspx

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Installing-and-Configuring-SharePoint-2010-and-FAST-Search-2010e28093Part-6.aspx